# Awstats Redirection Using Mod_Rewrite and Issue with Colon Symbol

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have spent hours trying to get `http://www.example.com/awstats` to redirect to `http://www.example.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=example.com`

The rewrite rule I used is:

```
RewriteRule ^https?://(www.)?(.*)/awstats/?$ /awstats/awstats.pl?config=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This doesn't work but it seems that it will work without the colon symbol.
I have tried using the HTML character code and escaping it but nothing I do seems to make any difference.

I have been testing it here: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/
If I supply this value:

```
http//www.example.com/awstats
```

With this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^https?//(www.)?(.*)/awstats/?$ /awstats/awstats.pl?config=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Then it works but obviously I need it to process the colon symbol.

Please can someone tell me what I am dong wrong?

Thanks
Robin

Comment: You have many errors. Instead, try this: `RewriteRule ^awstats/?$ /awstats/awstats.pl?config=example.com [L]`

Comment: Thanks for this but how is this going to pass the domain from the URL? I need something that will work for different domains and load the correct config. Rather than hard-coding it in I want to use it as part of the regular expression. What I have works when I test it online without the colon character so obviously the colon has some special significance but putting a backslash before it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It needs to handle both these examples: `http://www.example1.com/awstats > http://www.example1.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=example1.com` and also `http://www.example2.com/awstats > http://www.example2.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=example2.com`

Comment: I posted an answer taking this into consideration

Comment: Hello
Thanks for the replies but none of these would work for me for whatever reason but I worked out another way of doing it using PHP.
This works with whateverwebsite/awstats and forwards a user to the correct location:

`<?php  
$url = preg_replace('#^www\.(.+\.)#i', '$1', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);  
$location = 'awstats.pl?config='.$url;  
header( 'Location: '. $location);  
?>`

Posting it in case it is helpful for anyone else trying to do this with awstats.
I also added authentication in the .htaccess file to prevent it from being publically available.